# How to write the copyright symbol?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I want to put a copyright on my Form. I tried to write `&copy;`

```
private Label copyrightL = new Label("&copy;");
```

but it did not work. So how to write the © symbol ?

Answer (score 12):

Try with unicode symbol:

`private Label copyrightL = new Label("\u00a9");`

Hope this helps,

Comment: it doesnt work ! what is the key combinations to write the copyright symbol into a resource file ?

Comment: To write the copyright symbol into a file try with:  String copyright = "\u00a9";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/unicodefile.txt");
        fos.write(copyright.getBytes());
        fos.close();

Answer (score 1):

## Unicode code point number

Every character defined in Unicode has a unique integer number assigned to it.

Determine the number for your desired character. The [COPYRIGHT SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm) is decimal 169, hexadecimal A9.

Create a single-character string.

```
int copyrightSymbolCodePoint = 169 ;
String s = Character.toString( copyrightSymbolCodePoint ) ;
```

Or, append using a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "Copyright symbol is " ) ;
an.appendCodePoint( copyrightSymbolCodePoint ) ;
String output = sb.toString() ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hold alt key
Then press 0169 in numeric keyboard
Release alt
Enjoy

Comment: This is a programming site. Solutions must involve programming.

Answer (score -2):

Is it Java?, try using JLabel and use `private JLabel copyrightL = new JLabel("<html><body>&copy;</body></html>");`

Comment: It is Java (see the tags), but it's also LWUIT so `JLabel`s are not an option.